# How to get application state events in windows phone 7 and 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am making an app, in which whenever the app state changes (i.e Paused, Stop, Start, InBackground), i want to save some data for analytics purpose, and make a http call to my server.
I make r&d but nothing got relevent.
Any solution would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `App.xaml.cs` file look for event handlers that describe what you want to track.  I will post them here for reference.  It is up to you to keep track of the state of the App based on the firing of these events.  I should note that some of these events do have a time limit so running a cpu intensive routine in them is usually not a good idea.

```C#
// Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
// This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
// This code will not execute when the application is first launched
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is deactivated (sent to background)
// This code will not execute when the application is closing
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
}

// Code to execute when the application is closing (eg, user hit Back)
// This code will not execute when the application is deactivated
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I want to make a http request in Application_Deactivated, but it stops when application is in background.. how to do this.. thanx

Comment: @Akshay Afraid you only have a few seconds to complete what you want to do in the Deactivated handler.  You can search for the exact amount of time before it sends your app to the background.  Plus, I'm pretty sure a very limited things can happen during this time as well.  You might want to create some type of BackgroundProcess (like playing music in the background, downloading files in the background, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs there are events for Launching, Activation, Deactivation and Closing. You can write your codes in these events to save the data.

Refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx